# How to properly update program unatended from github?

Tags: git, shell, github, credentials

I have a python program that is started through a shell script on a raspberry Pi.
The program is located on the main branch in a github repository.

Right now, when i want to update the scrpt, i perform the update steps by hand in the terminal, because from time to time github request the login data again.

So what i need/have to do at the moment to update the program. I copy the sqlite DB (located in the program directory) to a directory one level higher, to not have it overwritten in the update process.
For this i already thought about permanently having it in directory not within the program, is that a good or bad idea?

After saving the db i perform a git fetch, where it usually requires the github login credentials.
Then i would like to perform a git commit and push to a seperate branch to backup the db in github.

The program might get rolled out to 2 other locations, i just thought about moving the db to a different directoy, that is its own repository, just for backing up the the db, seperate for each location.

Then i perform a hard reset to the origin main branch, as i found out that this works reliable.

After the update, i copy the db back in the the program directory and start the program.

Now i try to make the update automated and doable for non it personal by having the script read the exit code of the python program, that based on ui interaction sends a specific exit code to when the program should be updated. Then i want to start the update process in the shell script and restart the python program.
What i now don't know is how to properly set up the github connection/credentials, so that it doesn't get asked everytime, even after month of no update.

The following is my current shell script, where i planned on including the credentials in the git fetch command, which i know is as unsafe as possible, but i couldn't figure out how to properly do it.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Variables by default ##
DIR="/home/pi/Anwesenheitsnachweis"
DIR_BACKUP="/home/pi"
COMMIT_MESSAGE="db_backup"
GIT_BACKUP_BRANCH="db_backup"

## Variables added for handling in script ##
EXITCODE=0
#GIT_BRANCH_DEFAULT=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
GIT_BRANCH_DEFAULT="master"
BACKUP_FILE_NAME="DB.sqlite_$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")"

## Variables for execution at max mbp ##
#DIR="$HOME/git/AnwesenheitsnachweisPOC"
COMMIT_MESSAGE="db_backup $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")"
#GIT_BACKUP_BRANCH="db_backup_max"

function update_programm {
  #change to execution directory
  if ! cd "$DIR"; then
    echo "cannot change to execution directory"
    exit 1
  fi

  # create local backup with datetime of db file
  if ! cp DB.sqlite "$DIR_BACKUP"/"$BACKUP_FILE_NAME"; then
    echo "cannot copy $BACKUP_FILE_NAME to backup directory $DIR_BACKUP"
  fi

  # create local backup without datetime of db file
  if ! cp DB.sqlite "$DIR_BACKUP"; then
    echo "cannot copy $BACKUP_FILE_NAME to backup directory $DIR_BACKUP"
    exit 20
  fi

  #fetch remote changes
  if ! git fetch; then
    echo "cannot fetch remote changes"
    exit 3
  fi

  #change to backup branch to backup the dabatase file
  if ! git checkout "$GIT_BACKUP_BRANCH"; then
    echo "cannot change to backup branch"
    exit 31
  fi

  # retrieve local backup
  if ! cp "$DIR_BACKUP"/DB.sqlite "$DIR"; then
    echo "cannot copy retrieve backup"
    exit 33
  fi

  #create commit, even if no change was done with --allow-empty
  if ! git commit --allow-empty --all -m "$COMMIT_MESSAGE"; then
    echo "commit was not done"
    exit 34
  fi

  #create push to
  if ! git push --force; then
    echo "push was not done"
    exit 35
  fi

  #apply remote changes
  if ! git reset --hard origin/"$GIT_BRANCH_DEFAULT"; then
    echo "cannot apply remote changes"
    exit 4
  fi

  # retrieve local backup
  if ! cp "$DIR_BACKUP"/DB.sqlite "$DIR"; then
    echo "cannot copy retrieve backup"
    exit 33
  fi

  start_programm
}

function start_programm {
  #change to execution directory
  if ! cd "$DIR"; then
    echo "cannot change to execution directory"
    exit 1
  fi

  # create local backup with datetime of db file
  if ! cp DB.sqlite "$DIR_BACKUP"/"$BACKUP_FILE_NAME"; then
    echo "cannot copy $BACKUP_FILE_NAME to backup directory $DIR_BACKUP"
    #exit 2
  fi

  #start app
  python3 main.py
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    exit 0
  elif [ $? -eq 99]; then
    exit 99
  else
    exit 1
  fi

}



start_programm
```

What i tried is the code shown above. I am really curios to see a proper way to solve the github credential issue and how to properly manage the update process, with the db backup

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things in there you shouldn't do this way... But first, to sum up your steps:

1. copy sqliteDB from program directory to one directory higher
2. `git fetch` to get rid of the github login prompt
3. updates with `git commit` and `git push` to another branch, while you're working on your update.
4. `git reset --hard` on the main branch, when you found out your update works.
5. copy db back from directory one level higher into the program directory and restart the program

Things that should be different:

1. There is no need to copy the sqliteDB from the main branch to somewhere else. As it's checked in to git, you can reset changes on a single file at any point (as long as you didn't commit them yet) with `git checkout -- filepath`. Then you can also get rid of the `git reset --hard` part. Even though you *say* you work on a different branch, it doesn't feel like you understood what that means yet. Hint: Checking out a different branch means you are not working on the same version/instance of files any more.
2. Don't automate your github login. MFA is there for a reason.
3. Don't use `if ! <command>` to execute a command that does more than checking something. It'll derive you of features at some point. First execute the command, then check it's return code in an if-condition (as you did at the end with `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`).
4. Don't to `git push --force` *by default*. That's a bad no-no when you have more than one person working on a repository.
5. Not sure what you are trying to achieve with the empty commit in your script?
6. Whatever you're doing there is definitely not "doable for non it personal" as you desire it to be.
7. What you *probably* are trying to do is to create an automated backup of that database. You can just close youre program, commit your changes, restart the program and push your changes. That's it. History will be preserved, and no data is lost during the process. Also no file copying involved. Again, please read/experiment more on git.
8. Not sure on which end of the Anwesenheitsnachweis you are, but I highly recommend to not invest into cheating on your own presence or the presence of others. People tend to not receive that very well if it comes to the surface.
9. It sounds a lot like you're trying to automate your own development process. Instead of of investing time to automate it, try to ask yourself why your process feels so much like redundant work. In this case I'd say it's a hint your process is bad.

Comment: sorry i had to post my answer to your questions as a separate answer, as it was to long.

Answer (score 0):

As this was to long for a comment to the answer by thetillhoff from the 15. of may.

Thank you very much @thetillhoff for the extensive and very interesting and teaching answer.

I have some questions and some answers to your points:

1. I will have a deeper look into the git process, but for better understanding here is what i understood so far.

I have a master branch that contains the "working/released" versions of my program that can be rolled out to the devices (1-3 devices). For developing/working i create seperate branches to test and develop new features and when they are ready i merge the with the master branch to create a new "released" Version. In this master branch though i do not have the current db, just a mockup/testing db, as the db is updated and worked on, on the devices without me (people checking in).

Therefore when applying the new update on the devices i have to store/keep the local version of the db, which i did by copying elsewhere. If there is a way to fetch and checkout the new update without overwriting the local db, i will read about it and tryi it.

And because the local db changed, the standard "checkout" always prompted me with "do you want to overwrite the uncommited local changes".

2. Is there a proper way to update the local files from github without entering the credentials?
3. Alright thank you, i will use it in the future.
4. ok i will remove it.
5. I wanted to automate the update process, including pushing the local db to a backup branch. Occasions occured where i had no local changes, and when that happend the standard commit and push did not go through as there was nothing to change and the script stopped at that point.
6. my goal is to have a button in the ui to update the program, i will try and if i fail i fail.
7. i think this is answered above
8. yes i am fully aware of it.
9. i am trying to automate the rollout/update process, not the dev process.